# How to implement the feature introduced in higher version to lower version in Android

Tags: android, android-version

Can we use a feature that is introduced in higher version in lower versions. For example I have to use Toggle Switches in my application which has the  `android:minSdkVersion="4"`. But switch is introduced only from Android 4.0 (API level 14). Is there any way to implement switch option in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not a silly question, Google goes into quite a lot of detail about supporting different features across Android versions. You can read up on the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Adding support libraries to your application will allow backwards compatibility for a range of functions, but there are also other ways of handling these situations.

You can fork your code based on the current Android version installed on the device by performing a check and using a different control element.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    \\ USE A TOGGLE BUTTON
} else {
    \\USE SOMETHING ELSE!
}
```

This has disadvantages in branching your code to support different versions of Android.